# SSIS package to import text file then export excel

Tags: sql-server, ssis, append, export-to-excel

I need help making a SSIS package that will import a text then export an excel file that has four appended columns.

Example:
Take a text file like this:

```
First Name     Last Name
John           Minor
Larry          Johnson
```

And export an excel file this this:

```
First Name     Last Name     DOB            Address
John           Minor         01-26-1989     123 Main
Larry          Johnson       05-07-1998     456 Park
```

Comment: and where from do the `DOB` and `Address` come from?

Comment: Which part of it do you need help with?   What have you done so far, and where are you stuck?

Comment: Im pretty new to SSIS so I've just got it to scan a folder for the most recent text file and import that. I'm not sure how to append those extra columns and then export it to excel.

Comment: `First Name` and `Last Name` comes from text file and `DOB` and `Address` comes from SQL server database. Then how do you know that `01-26-1989` is the `DOB` of `John           `?

Comment: First Name, Last Name,  DOB and Address are in the database, but just First Name and Last Name are in the text file. So I was assuming once the text file was import you could it could get DOB and Address with a SQL command, like select DOB, address from person where first name = 'John' something like that